# multi-processor compilation error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have a project that compiles perfectly well when "Multi-processor Compilation" (/MP) is turned off. However, when that is turned on, it genetrates errors such as:

```
Error C2871: 'ADODB' : a namespace with this name does not exist
```

This is actually not a coding error , as said, compiling in one processor will work.

How could I fix it? To be fair, this is a legacy code that there are some looped header files includes.

Comment: You need to look at the code. Perhaps there's some preprocessor conditions to use a (non-existing) `ADODB` namespace when building with `/MP`? Perhaps you're missing some special header file?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't get it. There's no header file missing as, when compiled without `/MP`, it just goes smoothly. Also no preprocessor conditions interfere with `/MP` explicitly -- I only play around with `/NDEBUG` etc.

Comment: I mean that there might be some [*conditional compilation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_compilation) in the source, that does different things with `/MP` enabled, and for that "different things" you might need a header file you don't need when `/MP` is disabled. That's why you need to ***look at the code*** to see if there's any `#if`, `#ifdef` or `#ifndef` surrounding the use of the `ADODB` namespace. You should also try and find that namespace in the source and header files of the project, or search for it using your favorite search engine.

Comment: Make sure, you are not using any [Incompatible Options and Language Features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385193.aspx#Anchor_3). May be the `namespace` you are trying to use is `#import`ed which will not work with `/MP`.

Comment: @army007: Given that you get `ADODB` from `#import <msado15.dll>`, that's probably the correct answer.